# Are static members stored at fixed locations in .NET?

Tags: .net, interop, marshalling

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo
{
    static readonly Guid guid = Guid.Parse("...");
}
```

Can the underlying address of the static `guid` field change after initialization? If not, how can this address be obtained?

What about constants?

Note: I understand that reference types in general can be moved around by the GC (regardless of whether there's a static variable with a handle to them), but how does this work for static value types and constants?

This question came up as we're working on some code that requires interop with an unmanaged API, and we'd like to avoid doing an extra copy of the bytes into HGlobal if they're already at a fixed address in memory to begin with.

I'm more interested in knowing what the CLI standard says about this (versus what a specific .NET implementation *does*), since I prefer robust code that doesn't rely on a coincidental implementation detail.

Comment: Are you asking about the current implementations of .NET, or about what the CLI standard allows implementors to do under the hood?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are static class members pinned?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508517/are-static-class-members-pinned)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: The CLI standard, I suppose, although I'm always curious about implementation details :-)

Comment: @DStanley: Hmm, yes, thanks (how come I didn't see that when I searched!), but that doesn't entirely address the value type (and constants) aspect of my question.

Comment: @DStanley: As the linked question focuses on a specific framework version, but the OP here seems to be interested in the CLI standard, it doesn't seem to be a duplicate any more now (at first, I thought it was one, too). The difference might have to be explicitly pointed out in the question, though.

Comment: It is a jitter implementation detail.  Current jitters indeed store it in a fixed location.  But no way to obtain it yourself, only the jitter knows it and using the & operator in C# to generate a pointer produces an error.   That ends it.

Comment: @HansPassant: Alright then, that pretty much sums it up. Thanks! Submit an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard doesn't mention this, as far as I can tell - this isn't surprising, because it's definitely an implementation detail you shouldn't care about in a managed runtime.

Since you're looking to reuse this address in an unmanaged interop, I can put your mind to rest - you can't really access the address of those static fields in unsafe code. I don't know *why* (probably as some protection measure), but it seems to be the case.

Of course, noöne prevents you from making your own helper type that allocates a piece of unmanaged memory for whatever you want, and replace those fields with properties that read the unmanaged memory - you don't even have to care about the GC, since the static fields only die with the domain (usually the process) anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. That makes sense. I imagine it's the same for constants?

Comment: @Cameron Constants are usually inlined, so the difficulty is more obvious there :) It doesn't matter much anyway, since constants are primitives - references are usually more expensive than copying (about the same amount of data, but avoiding the indirection of a reference).

Comment: Ah, but there's constant strings too, which are reference types. But yes, I see your point. And inlining makes the whole thing moot, I forgot that happened.